# Disable sorting option in yii2

Tags: sorting, yii2

I'm new to Yii2 framework.
I have this Business view page like this..
[image]
Where for now a user can sort with all the four i.e business name, address, contact number and created date. I want to disable the sorting option for address and contact number. I found some options like 'sort' => false, but did not understand in which part of the code I should use it. Should I have to include the code in models? or controllers? or in the forms? Please help. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `'enableSorting' => false,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `enableSorting => false` disable sorting for particular column of GridView .
E.g.

```
   [
       'label' => 'Address',
       'attribute' => 'address',
       'enableSorting' => false,
    ],
```